# Dereferencing iterators performance

Tags: c, performance, pointers, memory

I have 3 functions that come down to the code below, that runs 800x800 times:

Each `while` loop below runs for exactly 800 times before `iter1 == lim`, so the duration was measured as it ran 800x800x800 (512 millions) times.

`iter1`, `iter2` and `lim` are `double` pointers. They point to a large enough vector of `double`'s.

`sum` is a `double` local variable.

`s1` and `s2` are local `unsigned int`'s, both equal to 800.

First runs in 2.257 seconds:

```
while ( iter1 < lim )
{
    sum += *iter1 * *iter2;
    ++iter1;
    iter2 += s2;
}
```

Second runs in 7.364 seconds:

```
while ( iter1 < lim )
{
    sum += *iter1 * *iter2;
    iter1 += s1;
    iter2 += s2;
}
```

Third runs in 1.355 seconds:

```
while ( iter1 < lim )
{
    sum += *iter1 * *iter2;
    ++iter1;
    ++iter2;
}
```

If I remove the `sum += *iter1 * *iter2;` instruction from each of them, they all run in around 1.07 seconds.

If I remove the second multiplication and change the instruction to `sum += *iter1;`, the first and third run in 1.33 seconds, while the second runs in 1.46 seconds.

If I remove the other iterator, like this: `sum += *iter2;`, then the first and second run in around 2.2 seconds, while the third runs in 1.35 seconds.

Obviously, the performance drop is tied to the quantity added to `iter1` and `iter2`. I am no expert in how the processor accesses memory and dereferences pointers, so I hope someone in the community knows more than me and is willing to shed some light on my problem.

If you need any information about the hardware I ran these tests on, or anything else that can prove helpful, feel free to ask in the comments.

EDIT: The problem is that the second function was slow, when compared to the others, and wanted to know if there is anything I can do to make it run faster, as it appeared to be doing similar things like the other 2.

EDIT 2: All the measurements were made in Release build

Comment: " so I hope someone in the community knows more than me and is willing to shed some light on my problem " , what is the problem ?

Comment: I do not really understand what is your "problem", you tried different versions, you found one is faster, so just use it... did I miss something?

Comment: Wait, so you are adding 800 to your iterators and it works?

Comment: Every block is doing a different thing, you can't compare performance this way and obtain meaningful results. (++iter1 is not the same as iter1+=s1, since s1 is 800).

Comment: Are you testing a **release**, **optimized** build?  If not, then these numbers and observations you're showing us are meaningless.  When a question of performance is asked, it should require you to specify in your question the compiler and build/optimization settings.

Comment: @tobi303 I need all of them.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Why wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a manifestation of data locality.
It takes less time to look at something at the next page of a book than something at the 800th next page. Try for yourself at home.

Comment: "It takes less time to look at something at the next page of a book than something at the 800th next page" . When I only used one of the iter's, the second function ran almost as fast as the other 2, despite the iterator being added 800. Why is it so much more time consuming when I add another iterator that is being added 800 at each step? Shouldn't the performance drop be less than "4 times slower" or is the memory being accesed the same time something else is done?

Comment: The variation in time is due to deferencing, ie `*iter1` and `*iter2`, not the arithmetic operations on the iterators. So not only by removing an iterator you are reducing the number of memory accesses, you are also making accesses more uniform. Which may open the way to all kind of optimizations.

Answer (score 5):

The performance difference has nothing to do with the iterators.  The difference is in the extra cache misses from advancing through a large amount of data with greater than unit stride.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the resulting machine code, depending on the sofistication of your compiler/platform.

To retrieve a pointer value, the internal machine will utilize something like a LOAD instruction, lets call the fictional assembler code `LD addr0`.

`addr0` refers to the address register that is used.

A lot of CPUs provide statements like `LD addr0+` that increment the address after loading the stored value. Often, this additional increment does not lead to any extra cycles.

I worked with some compilers that could only generate the `addr0+` statements if the address increment is done by the increment operator directly after or in the dereferenciation statement.

So the last one could be the example with the most efficient machine code.

It would be interesting if you could post the resulting assembler code of the compilation process for each of the example.

Comment: I looked at Dissasembly my IDE ( Visual Studio 2012 ) generated, and it was pretty straight-forward and wasn't doing any extra things. I never saw any LOAD instruction, so I guess it's something else you requested.